# Finding ratio of areas of similar triangles

Tags: geometry, triangles, area

Find the ratio of the areas of triangles $XOY:XOM:MON$.

[image]

---

I'm able to find the ratio of $XOY$ and $MON$ using the similar triangle formulas, which makes it $4:25$. Unsure about $XOM$. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can one use area of triangle = $\frac{1}{2}$ (side 1)(side 2) sin(angle between the sides)$

Comment: How are those triangles "solids"? (Would you like to edit the title of your question?)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: (1) What is $XO:ON$ (or $MO:OY$)? (2) Triangles $MOX$ and $YOX$ have different bases but the same height. Why is the ratio of their areas the same as the ratio of their bases?

Comment: I see. I understand now. Thanks